# Number of solutions to quadratic equations modulo a power prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $q = p^k$.

How can we determine the number of solutions modulo $q$ to the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ for general $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

When $p$ does not divide $a$, the equation is then equivalent to $(2ax+b)^2 = b^2-4ac$, and we can easily get the answer by considering $y^2 = b^2-4ac$ modulo $q$.

What if $p$ divides $a$ then?

Comment: You also need $p \ne 2$ for that manipulation to work. E.g. $x^2+2x+1=0$ mod $4$ has the solutions $1$ and $3$, but $(2x+2)^2 = 2^2-4$ mod $4$ has $4$ solutions.

Comment: @ZoeAllen Thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

When $q=p$ the situation is clear.

For higher powers of $p$ one can set up an inductive procedure as follows that actually works for every polynomial $P(X)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

Suppose that we know a solution $a\bmod p^k$. Then we can  look at the conguence
$$
P(a+tp^k)\equiv 0\bmod p^{k+1}
$$
(here $t$ is the unknown).
After some simplifications this reduces to a congruence $\bmod p$ which allows, if soluble, to lift a root $\bmod p^k$ to a root $\bmod p^{k+1}$.

In order to reduce this infinite sequence of congruences to one single "thing" one needs to introduce the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and prove [Hensel's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma).